# how to check if a database field's value has been changed in django?

Tags: python, django, database

hi I am trying to code an ecommerce website with django , is there any way to check if a model's field's value has been changed?
for example I like to send the customer a message after his/her order status has changed.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Order(models.Model):
  user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  status=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='pending')
  # other firlds ...


@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def send_sms_if_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    #what should i write ? 
    # if instance.status has changed : 
    #  send_sms(to=instance.owner.phone,message=f'your order status is {order.status}')
```

Comment: You'll either have to write a [custom signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals) or do it inside the `save` method.